# Как в реальном времени проверять стоит темная тема или светлая?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив картинок для светлой темы и для темной.
Я смог все же сделать, чтобы при смене темы на темную или светлую и обновлении страницы менялась картинка из нужного массива. **Но нужно**, чтобы менялась сразу при смене темы без обновлении страницы.

Было бы круто, если подсказали бы как сократить этот код:

```
const randomBg = document.getElementById('randomBg'),
        imagesLight = ['какие-то картинки'],
        imagesDark = ['какие-то картинки']

const imgCountDark = imagesDark.length,
        numberDark = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgCountDark),
        imgCountLight = imagesLight.length,
        numberLight = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgCountLight)
```

Что нужно написать здесь, чтобы менялось сразу, а не после обновления страницы?

```
const getCurrentBg = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? window.onload = function() {
    randomBg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagesDark[numberDark]})`
} : window.onload = function() {
    randomBg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imagesLight[numberLight]})`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В функции `getCurrentBg` в тернарнике оставить только строки, задающие `background`, без всяких обёрток в виде `window.onload = function() {`
2. Отдельно вне функции `getCurrentBg` сделать её вызов при перезагрузке, т.е.

   ```
   window.onload = () => { getCurrentBg() }
   ```
3. При клике на ссылку или кнопу смены темы тоже вызывать функцию `getCurrentBg()`

Comment: Так правильно?
themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => { getCurrentBg() })

Я новичок поэтому уточняю:)

Comment: Можно просто `themeButton.addEventListener('click',getCurrentBg)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/change_event)

В примере ниже функция screenTest вызывается сразу же при изменении темы

```js
const mql = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

function screenTest(e) {
  const para = document.querySelector("p");
  if (e.matches) {
    para.textContent = "Current theme: dark";
  } else {
    para.textContent = "Current theme: light";
  }
}

mql.addEventListener("change", screenTest);
screenTest(mql);
```

```css
body {
  color: #530;
  background-color: #fed;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    background-color: #ffe;
    color: #000;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: #234;
    color: #fec;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Current theme: ????</p>
```

Comment: Та как менять тему мне не надо. Мне просто картинку поменять на фоне, когда меняется цветовая тема.
И если знаешь в чем отличие, полностью в js описывать смену темы и как у тебя?